# Jmeter Extracting Json response with contains and not included condition

Tags: json, api, jmeter, response

I would like to ask for your assistance regarding this scenario below because I want to extract all values version without RC txt. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you

Sample Response
[{
"version": "2-325"
},
{
"version": "2-327RC2565"
}, {
"version": "2-326"
}, {
"version": "2-327RC256"
}]

I want to combine contains and not included syntax however I'm getting an error

Expected Result:
Only Values will be extracted **2-325**  & **2-326**

**Note the version content is dynamic.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looking for the `version` attributes which don't contain `RC`, it could be done using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

An example one:

```
$..[?(@.version =~ /((?!RC).)*/)]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much.